# How to see all possible query sets of a model in django

Tags: python, django

I have two models like below in django

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(....)
    last_name = models.CharField(_(....)
    email = models.EmailField(...)

class VcsToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

as you can see `VcsToken` is related to User, and a user can have many `VcsToken`,

1. So how do I get all the `VcsTokens` of a `User`.
2. Similarly I have many one to many relationships from user to other models, so How do I know their reference name? (I know its a `set` but how do I know the set name? ) Is there any way to list the query set names for a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given `User` object `myuser`, you can access this with:

```
myuser.vcstoken_set.all()
```

> so How do I know their reference name?

This is the value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) if there is no such parameter in the `ForeignKey` construction, it will default to `modelname_set`, with the *`modelname`* in lowercase.

> Is there any way to list the query set names for a model.

You can access all `ManyToOneField`s with:

django.db.models.fields.reverse_related.ManyToOneRel

```
[f.get_accessor_name() for f in User._meta.get_fields() if isinstance(f, ManyToOneRel)]
```

This will construct a list of the names of `ForeignKey`s in reverse.

Comment: Thank you :), The convention got confused me. I was trying with the plural version

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the feature for walking backward on the foreign key relationships. This is covered here in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

In your example you should be able to access VcsToken from User like this:

```py
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)  # let's get an example user
user.vcstoken_set.all()  # returns all related VcsToken objects.
```

Optionally, when the ForeignKey is defined, you can specify a `related_name` argument that would be used by django for this purpose. For example:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    email = models.EmailField(...)

class VcsToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tokens')
```

If such an argument is specified, then that is the reverse lookup name used by django and you would need to do `user.tokens.all()` to access them. When no such argument is specified a default name is used by django that ends with "_set".

Hope this helps, let me know if anything needs to be clarified.